# Logging in readable Plink output (sshlog is too clumsy)

Tags: windows, batch-file, terminal, putty, plink

I'm logging into to a remote SSH session using `plink.exe` to perform certain tasks using a batch script. Getting the output of these commands in a log file as well on the screen is very important for me.

I tried using usual batch way i.e.

```
plink servername -m cmd.txt>logfile.log
```

But the problem with this is that it wont display it on the Windows terminal that the batch script is running on.

Then I found the `-sshlog` option of Plink. This does the work, i.e. I can get the output on screen and in a log file, but this results in output as follows:

[image]

My actual output starts at `te....` in the image above
The output has these `00000010  74 65 72 ... bla bla` characters which I don't want. Plus the main output (that would be displayed if I was using Plink interactively is "word-wrapped" and looks horrible which makes it very difficult to understand for a general user

Is there any way to prevent plink output unwanted `-sshlog` characters in the log file?
or
Is there any other way to get the output on screen and log fail simultaneously in a Plink/PuTTY session inside a batch script?